# How does new site provisioning work in Area51?

Tags: discussion, area-51, beta-phase

When a new Area 51 Beta site is launched, I reckon it needs a bunch of resources like a subdomain, new web application, possibly an app pool and a DB.

How does SE currently provision these resources? Is it automatic or manual?